# Powershell gci in a function. Pass filename variables with wildcards into the function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I was trying to pass parameters to a function to do get-childitem. Seems it cannot be done. Furthermore I can't delete my post so I'm just emptying it out with a basic explanation of what I was trying to figure out. Seems I cannot pass filename variables with wildcards in them. Every answer in here so far does not help me as everything I've tried generates a zero byte file.

```
Function getFilenames($facPath,$facility,[string[]]$fileIncludes) {

    gci $facPath\* -Include $fileIncludes -Recurse | 
      Select-Object @{ expression={$_.name}; label='FILENAME' },
      @{Name='FACILITY';Expression={$facility}} | 
      Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $scriptPath"\filenames.txt" -Append

  }

getFilenames $vPath "Building 1" $vFiles
```

Comment: You must call the function like `getFilenames $vpath "Building1" $vFiles` or `getFilenames($vPath)("Building1")($vFiles)`. The method call syntax will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your function to the following. I removed several `Select-Object` commands because you only need one.

```
Function getFilenames($facPath,$facility,[string[]]$fileIncludes) {

    gci $facPath -Include $fileIncludes | 
      Select-Object @{ expression={$_.name}; label='FILENAME' },
      @{Name='FACILITY';Expression={$facility}} | 
      Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "$scriptPath\filenames.txt" -Append

  }
```

You can run this like the following:

```
getFilenames "c:\folder\facilities\*" "manufacturing" "ab*","cd*","ef*"
```

PowerShell determines a string array by various notations:

- `"string1","string2","stringx"`: Comma-separated list
- `[string[]]$stringArray`: Typing or casting
- `@("string1","string2","string3")`: Array sub-expression

See [About Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6) for more information on using Arrays.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same results on this, it's producing a zero byte file

Comment: Does your $facPath value include a wildcard?

Comment: UNC network paths, folders only no wildcards.
"'\\exchange\folder\folder\etc"

Comment: it is [string[]]$fileIncludes which has the wildcards because these filenames have datestamps

Comment: $facPath needs to have a trailing wildcard if you are going to use `-Include`. We can add that to the function so that you don't have to input it, so you must use "'\\exchange\folder\folder\etc\\*" or use the `-Recurse` parameter instead.

Comment: Thank you, I did do that and I'm back to the wildcard error
    Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic 
    parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard 
    character pattern is not valid:

Comment: Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: CCPSAsimfolder Building1 System.Object[]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191625/discussion-between-adminofthings-and-shadoe2020).

Comment: Based on how you have defined your variables, `gci -path $ccpsaPath -Recurse -Include $ccpsaFiles` will retrieve the files. If you use my version of the function, you will need to execute `getFileNames "$ccpsaPath\*" "Facility" $ccpsaFiles`.

Comment: You are trying to call `getFilenames` using the `()` notation. PowerShell by default sees `()` as control structures, so a typical function can't be called like `getFilenames($Arg1,$Arg2,$arg3)`. It treats everything in () in this example as a string expression. The nearest thing you can do to that is `getFilenames("$ccpsaPath\*")("Facility")($ccpsaFiles)`.

Comment: So basically I just cannot put this into a function

Comment: Yes, you can. You just have to call it in a way that PowerShell likes. If you follow my post, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$Include=@("ab*","cd*","ef*")
Get-Childitem -Recurse -Include $Include
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not
supported.

I feel like this should have worked. Thanks